# Unable to find a specific GRASS add-on in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, add-ons

I would like to use the r.xtent add-on made for GRASS GIS (http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.xtent/description.html) in QGIS using the GRASS plugin, but I can't seem to find it.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you want is not in the latest QGIS processing toolbox either.

It seems that it contains only core GRASS functions, but no add-ons.

Compare http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/trunk/raster/ with http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/

GRASS can be run independent from QGIS, and you can add those extensions there following: http://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/.

But you might not have access to it via the old GRASS plugin or the Processing toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

This feature (possibility to install custom addons) will be implemented soon (I hope):
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53048